# Is something like MaxKeepAliveRequests supported in Kestrel in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Apache has an option named `MaxKeepAliveRequests` that limits how many requests a given TCP connection can be reused for. I would like to have that feature in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application that uses the built-in Kestrel server. I have read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and some blogs, but as far as I can see this option does not exist. The closest thing is the timeout for an idle connection and that doesn't help when the connections are in active use.

Is there a well-hidden option that does this? If not, can it be solved with some code (without customizing Kestrel itself)? Any examples?

I'm really trying to solve the problem where calling applications fail to load balance with newly added nodes as they keep connections to old nodes alive, so an alternative would be to find client-side solutions with `HttpClient` and Angular. However, with Apache I would have been able to fix it in minutes on the server for all clients in one swoop, so if it is possible to achieve with Kestrel with reasonable effort that would be great!

Comment: Is that what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserverlimits.keepalivetimeout?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Comment: No, that is the timeout I mentioned. It closes an idle connection after a given time. I would like to close an active connection after a certain number of requests or by all means after a given time, so that the client is forced to open a new connection.

Comment: How did you host your application? Hosting in Kestrel directly or hosting behind a reverse proxy server? For `KestrelServerLimits`, there is no such settings, since you could host .net core behind a reverse proxy, and apache have the feature `MaxKeepAliveRequests`, you could try use Kestrel with a reverse proxy `Apache`. Check [When to use Kestrel with a reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy)

Comment: We are in Kubernetes behind Nginx, so I could probably do it in the reverse proxy, but the micro-services call each other directly through the Kubernetes services. Making them go through the reverse proxy would be a possible solution, but it would add latency. They are a bit chatty in places, so I'd like to avoid that.